# How to get the list of users in MySQL with date of creation?

Tags: mysql, sql

how to get the list of users in MySQL with date of creation, associated privileges, etc.

If I type.

```
SELECT User FROM mysql.user;
```

output will be like this.

```
+-------+
| User  |
+-------+
| root  |
+-------+
| user2 |
+-------+
| user3 |
+-------+
```

how can I see that?

Answer (score 2):

The default mysql.User table has no datetime column to track when the user was added or any other date for that matter.

You *can* add one yourself. This will not help you with users added in the past, but it will help you going forward.

```
ALTER TABLE User ADD COLUMN date_added TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
```

and you'll get all info except date of creation. I doubt you can achieve user creation dates as they are not stored in the  database.

or you can select the specific fields by typing

```
DESC mysql.user;
```

Comment: thanks but this i found on google also.http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/mysql/show-users-i-ve-created-in-mysql-database

Comment: You can try search for the creation date in mysql log file (if there is any and you can access it)